# Display Ads Randomly with PHP

Tags: php, web, random, echo, ads

I have a website built with php. I have an ad in between two paragraphs. The developer who built this for me had set it for 2 ads to be randomly displayed everytime a user views the page. However, I have got 2 more clients who want to advertise in the slot therefore I need 4 ads to be displayed randomly. but I cannot get it to work on my own. I think this would be a really simple fix so didnt want to ask and trouble the developer.

The actual code

```
<?php   rand(1,2); //rand(1,2);// rand(1,2); 
        if($ranVal==1) { ?>
        <a href="http://www.dhiraagu.com.mv/" target="_blank"><img style="width:100%;  margin:1em 0;" class="load-delay" src="../images/blk_topR.png" data-original="../images/advert/dhir_rt.png" alt="Dhiraagu"/></a>
        <?php } if($ranVal==2) { ?>
        <a href="https://munihomecare.com/" target="_blank"><img style="width:100%;  margin:1em 0;" class="load-delay" src="../images/blk_topR.png" data-original="../images/advert/muni.png" alt="muni" /></a>
        <?php } ?>
```

What changes should I make to add two more ad slots. 1 ad sh[hould be visible each time but should randomly change between the 4 every time the page is refreshed.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php should give you a fairly big clue

Answer (score 1):

for me, I'd probably do something like

```
<?php
 $a = array(
  1 => array( "link" => "link", "img" => "img_link", "alt" => "alt_text"),
  2 => array( "link" => "link", "img" => "img_link", "alt" => "alt_text"),
  3 => array( "link" => "link", "img" => "img_link", "alt" => "alt_text")
 );

 $b = $a[rand(1, sizeof($a))];
 echo $b["img"];
?>
```

so you can put only this code

```
<a href="<?=$b["link"];?>" target="_blank"><img style="width:100%;  margin:1em 0;" class="load-delay" src="<?=$b["img"];?>" data-original="../images/advert/muni.png" alt="<?=$b["alt_text"];?>" /></a>
```

Comment: Nice, but you can probably make it even simpler with [`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)